# Filtering with a only one conditional

Tags: python, lambda, filter

I'm trying to write a code that uses only lambdas, filter, map and reduce (its a riddle) that accepts a tuple of integers and a tuple of functions, and returns a new tuple of integers who only return **one** true from the list of functions:

As an example, if the tuple is `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)` and the tuple of functions is `(lambda x: x > 3, lambda x: x % 2 == 0)`  I should get a new tuple that looks like `[2, 5, 7, 9]` because they make only one of the two rules to return True. this is my code so far and I have no idea how to do that...

```
func = (lambda x: x > 3, lambda x: x % 2 == 0)
data = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)

a = lambda func, data: tuple(filter(lambda x: tuple(filter(None, map(lambda f: f(x), func))), data))
print(a(func, data))
```

This code returns only the integers that apply to both of the terms, but I need to make it to just **one**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is:

```
a = lambda func, data: tuple(filter(lambda d: (sum(map(lambda f: f(d), func)) == 1), data))
```

Since this really is just a contrived exercise for the sake of it I won't endeavor explaining this horrible expression. But the way to get to it is to first write the code in a clear way with `for` loops, `if` blocks etc..., and then one step at a time replace each component with the appropriate `map`, `filter` etc...

The one trick I use here is automatic boolean conversion to int: `sum(sequence_of_bool) == 1` means exactly one bool is `True`.

My full test code:

```
func = (lambda x: x > 3, lambda x: x % 2 == 0)
data = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
a = lambda func, data: tuple(filter(lambda d: (sum(map(lambda f: f(d), func)) == 1), data))
print(a(func, data))

(2, 5, 7, 9)
```

Comment: Well I try to print it like this: print(a(func,data)) and it returns an empty string

Comment: Awesome it works! but can you do it without sum? is it possible? ( I don't know if its  part of the riddle)

Comment: `sum` is really just  `reduce(add, ...)`

Comment: could you explain to me this trick ? sum(sequence_of_bool) == 1

Comment: `sum(map(lambda b: 1 if b else 0, sequence_of_bool))` is clear? Well automatic conversion from bool to int is exactly that: 1 if b else 0.

Comment: Yes I saw it works when I try sum([true,false,false])==1 it returns true, but why does it work that way? I cant find any reference of that in the documentation.

Comment: Python is clever enough to do automatic conversions when possible, and also has default arguments. `sum` has a default argument `start=0` which means it accumulates from `0` unless you tell it to do otherwise. So as it sees the bools coming it will try to add a bool to an int, thus will convert the bool to int using the rule `True -> 1` and `False -> 0`.

Comment: awesome thank you! and just if you don't mind could you should me how can I swap sum to reduce in your code? ( for educational purposes) thank you!

Comment: Just as I said: `sum(seq) -> reduce(add, seq))`. You can import `add` from `operator` and `reduce` from `functools`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bool.__xor__` to ensure that only one of the two functions in the `func` tuple is satisfied:

```
from functools import reduce
tuple(filter(lambda x: reduce(bool.__xor__, map(lambda f: f(x), func)), data))
```

This returns:

```
(2, 5, 7, 9)
```

Comment: thank you but I cant use bool.__xor__ can I do it without it?

Comment: `reduce(bool.__xor__, [True,False,True,False,True])` is `True`, not what OP wants...

Comment: @Julien The output of that expression is then used as a `lambda` function for `filter`, which does produce what OP wants.

Comment: My point is `xor(seq)` is not the same as "exactly one `True` in `seq`".

Comment: To say it bluntly, your statement "You can use bool.__xor__ to ensure that only one of the two functions in the func tuple is satisfied" becomes false as soon as you have possibly more than 2 functions.